# gscan2pdf won't work using Brother DCP7065DN

Tags: scanner

Just after new install via Brother website instructions of downloaded drivers.

```
~/Downloads $ scanimage -L
device `brother4:bus6;dev2' is a Brother DCP-7065DN USB scanner

~/Downloads $ cd /dev/bus/usb/002
/dev/bus/usb/002 $ sudo chmod 666 /dev/bus/usb/002/006
chmod: cannot access '/dev/bus/usb/002/006': No such file or directory

/dev/bus/usb/002 $ ls
001  002  003  004  005
```

From 60-libsane.rules

```
# For Linux >= 2.6.22 without CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_CLASS=y
# If the following rule does not exist on your system yet, uncomment it
 ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", OWNER="root", GROUP="root"

# Kernel < 2.6.22 jumps here
LABEL="libsane_usb_rules_begin"
```

Comment: so from this page http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/index.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on one goes to the FAQ http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on and 1) http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on#f00107 `sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4` and ... go to next comment below ..

Comment: 2)http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on#f00101 you have brscan4 so `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1.0.7 /usr/lib/sane` and `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so /usr/lib/sane` and `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1 /usr/lib/sane` and 3) if usb http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on#u13.04 install the udev rule